# Geodesics in Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Suppose you wanted to know the geodesic between two points in a manifold, where the points do not exist in the same chart. Would the fact that they are not in the same chart make a difference? How would you work out the components of the metric when they are dependent on locally defined tangent vectors but your curve exists in multiple coordinate charts?